# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '_renderItem' of undefined (Autocomplate)

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to make ajax code works with multiple input fields in the same time ?

> Error: 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '_renderItem' of undefined'

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#AutoComplete", "#AutoComplete2", "#AutoComplete3").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {

        $.ajax({
            url: '/Company/Search',
            type: 'GET',
            cache: false,
            data: request,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                response($.map(data, function (item) {

                    return {
                        label: item.firstname + ' ' + item.lastname + ' ',
                        value: item.id,
                        image: item.picture,
                        siteurl: item.siteurl
                    }
                }))
            }
        });
    },
```

Comment: Please confirm that id of each input control is correct. This error indicates that jquery selector is not able to an element with given id.

Answer (score 0):

```
                                        <label>Recruiter Name: </label>
                                    <input asp-for="Company.Admin1_Id" class="form-control" id="AutoComplete" name="AutoComplete" autocomplete="off" />
                                    <input asp-for="Company.Admin1_Id" type="hidden" id="AutoCompleteHidden" autocomplete="off" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Recruiter Name: </label>
                                    <input asp-for="Company.Admin2_Id" class="form-control" id="AutoComplete2" name="AutoComplete2" autocomplete="off" />
                                    <input asp-for="Company.Admin2_Id" type="hidden" id="AutoCompleteHidden2" autocomplete="off" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Recruiter Name: </label>
                                    <input asp-for="Company.Admin3_Id" class="form-control" id="AutoComplete3" name="AutoComplete3" autocomplete="off" />
                                    <input asp-for="Company.Admin3_Id" type="hidden" id="AutoCompleteHidden3" autocomplete="off" />
                                </div>
```